# Using Canvas to dynamically draw from set coordinates with delay

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I am trying to use HTML canvas and JS to create short stop motion video animations from an array of set coordinates. My thinking is that I should be able to loop over the array, and use the canvas lineTo method with a setInterval between each iteration. However, so far I have not been able to make each line appear after a set time. Rather, the interval waits, and then renders all the lines together (so I end up with an image appearing after X time, rather than a stop motion video of the image slowly being created).

So far I have tried changing the order of operations, wrapping the whole thing in a setTimeout that recalls itself (instead of setInterval), to the same effect.

(I am incrementing i by 2 because testArr is an array that alternates X and Y coordinates)

```
$("#go").on("click", function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("defaultCanvas0");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(testArr[0], testArr[1]);
  for (let i = 2; i < testArr.length; i += 2) {
    function timeloop() {
      ctx.lineTo(testArr[i], testArr[i + 1]);
      ctx.stroke();
      setTimeout(timeloop, 3000);
    }

    if (typeof testArr[i + 3] === "number") {
      timeloop();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a loop for what you're trying to achieve. You need a recursive `setInterval` and a global index. You also have to call `ctx.beginPath()`, `ctx.moveTo(...)`, `ctx.lineTo()` and `ctx.stroke()` on every iteration.

```js
const testArr = [50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50];

var c = document.getElementById("defaultCanvas0");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var i = 2; // You need a global variable to track progress

$("#go").on("click", function() {
  function timeloop() {
    // You have to beginPath and stroke each loop
    // Therefore you need moveTo each loop aswell
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(testArr[i-2], testArr[i-1]);
    ctx.lineTo(testArr[i++], testArr[i++]);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Check if another iteration should happen
    if (i+1 < testArr.length) { setTimeout(timeloop, 1000); }
  }
  timeloop();
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="go">GO</button>
    <canvas id="defaultCanvas0"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. One question: where is i being incremented? I see you i++ in the ctx.lineTo method, but you are using that as a coordinate. Would that increment the global i variable?

Comment: Yes, `i++` anywhere would increment `i`. Instead of doing `i+1`, `i+2` and then `i += 2`, it's easier to just increment it on the spot.